# Prove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt {1+a} \geq \frac{\sqrt 2}{3} (a+b+c)^2$ for $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \leq 3$.
> Prove $$\sqrt {1+a} +\sqrt {1+b} +\sqrt {1+c} \geq \frac{\sqrt 2}{3} \cdot(a+b+c)^2$$

I am unsure of where to even start. I know that $$\sqrt 2 \geq \frac{\sqrt 2}{3} \cdot\left(a^2 +b^2 +c^2\right)$$  which is needed for solving it, but otherwise I am unsure of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The desired inequality is written as
$$\sqrt {\frac{1+a}{2}} +\sqrt {\frac{1+b}{2}} +\sqrt {\frac{1+c}2} \geq \frac{1}{3} \cdot(a+b+c)^2.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{\frac{1+a}2} &= \frac{1 + a}{2\sqrt{\frac{1+a}{2}}}\\
 &\ge \frac{1 + a}{1 + \frac{1+a}{2}} \qquad\qquad  (\mbox{AM-GM})\\
 &= \frac{2(1 + a)}{3 + a}\\
 &= \frac{2(1 + a)}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1 - a}{4}}\\
 &\ge \frac{2(1 + a)}{4}\cdot \left(1 + \frac{1 - a}{4}\right) \\
 &= \frac58 + \frac12 a - \frac18 a^2 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we use $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1 - a}{4}} \ge 1 + \frac{1 - a}{4}$ (using $0 \le a \le \sqrt 3 < 2$).

Similarly, we have $\sqrt{\frac{1+b}2} \ge \frac58 + \frac12 b - \frac18 b^2$ and $\sqrt{\frac{1+c}2} \ge \frac58 + \frac12 c - \frac18 c^2$.

Thus, we have
$$\sqrt {\frac{1+a}{2}} +\sqrt {\frac{1+b}{2}} +\sqrt {\frac{1+c}2}
\ge \frac{15}8+ \frac12 (a+b+c) - \frac18 (a^2+b^2+c^2).
$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{15}8+ \frac12 (a+b+c) - \frac18 (a^2+b^2+c^2)
\ge \frac13\cdot (a + b + c)^2$$
or
$$\frac{15}8+ \frac12 (a+b+c) - \frac18 \cdot 3
\ge \frac13\cdot (a + b + c)^2$$
or
$$\frac16(2a + 2b + 2c + 3)(3 - a - b - c)\ge 0$$
which is true using
$a + b + c \le \sqrt{3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)} \le 3$.

We are done.

Comment: Did "$a + b + c \le \sqrt{3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)} \le 3
$" follow from Cauchy Schwarz? (+1)

Comment: @DS Thanks. We can use C-S.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to where the 15/8 comes from, it that just a typo or is it supposed to be 15/8?

Comment: @xlixir It is $\frac58 + \frac12 a - \frac18 a^2 + \frac58 + \frac12 b - \frac18 b^2 + \frac58 + \frac12 c - \frac18 c^2$.

Comment: @xlixir I edited the answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes it is clear now, Thank you!

Comment: @xlixir Your are welcome.